# Source attachment does not contain the source for the file MenuInflater.class

Tags: java, android

### My code is as follows:

```
package chapter.seven;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;

public class UserInterface extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)
    {
        MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.mainmenu, menu);
        return true;
    }
    }
```

---

when I run it through the emulator, I keep getting the following error:

Class File Editor
Source Not Found!

The source attachment does not contain the source for the file MenuInflater.class
You can change the source attachment by clicking change Attached Source below:

I don't understand why it cannot find the MenuInflater.class. I have looked all over the internet and cannot find a solution. Please help!

Comment: What version of Android are you running against? Show us the uses=sdk tag from your manifest

Comment: stack trace is always helpful, too

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="chapter.seven"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i think you need to call super.(super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);)

Comment: I have tried several different coding options to no avail. I think that it is a problem in the setup of my computer. Does anybody know where the MenuInflater.class is? I'm hoping that I can just troubleshoot it by telling Java where to look for the class.